# Disk Usage 100% after booting from another hard drive

Tags: windows-10, boot, external-hard-drive, windows-server-2012-r2

### Problem Overview

I decided to put my school hard drive into my home computer to migrate some VM's.
After booting into the school hard drive and moving the virtual machines, I had taken out the school hard drive, booted from my machines original hard drive.

Now I am getting long boot times, and 100% disk usage.
It also usually takes long to log in.

I believe this is a driver issue.

My home PC hard drive runs Windows 10
The school hard drive uses Windows Server 2012 R2

### Troubleshootig Step Taken

I have tried using chkdsk /f and sfc /scannow
I even tried a system restore but it failed to restore.

Comment: look if the drive cache is still enabled in device manager

Comment: didn't work. Might I add that the DVD drive keeps being polled when I boot. I also enable verbose Boot, so i could see if I what was taking so long to load on boot, but i only got verbose messages on shut down, not on boot.

Comment: sorry. I do get verbose messages. The message usually gets stuck on "Preparing Windows".

Comment: I have had this issue when I was running Windows 10 Insider Preview, but the issue was resolved when I removed myself from Insider Preview builds.

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0 to capture 2 minutes. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxp30OOH_g13MnlmQ0lOb3lDV2s/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see the write cache works and is enabled and fragmentation is 0%:

[image]

But in the data, I can see that the offsets are large and the disk has to move the Head stack very often to read data.

[image]

This moving of the read/write head assembly of the hdd causes delays with a large Queue Depth at Init of over 195 (195 other operation are already pending before the requested one could be done).

[image]

This is very bad. Everything over 10 is causing delays.

1 idea is that the other windows uses a different algorytm for the defrag tool and moved the files at those offsets. So defrag the drive again on Windows 10 and hope it improves the situation.

But the only real fix is to repalce the HDD with a SSD.

Comment: Thanks :) . The boot time is much better now. About 15 seconds.